# Why allocation and sort of std::pair is faster than std::vector?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, std-pair

Today I just tried to solve a problem in programming. I noticed that allocation and sorting of the vector<vector> are much much slower than vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>. I took some benchmarks and came to know that nested vector code is 4x slower than nested pair code for the given input (https://pastebin.com/izWGNEZ7).

Below is the code I used for benchmarking.

```
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> edges;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.size(); j++)
            edges.push_back({abs(points[i][0] - points[j][0]) + abs(points[i][1] - points[j][1]), {i, j}});
    sort(edges.begin(), edges.end());
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double elapsed_time_ms = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end - t_start).count();
    cout << elapsed_time_ms << endl;

    auto t_start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    vector<vector<int>> edges1;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.size(); j++)
            edges1.push_back({abs(points[i][0] - points[j][0]) + abs(points[i][1] - points[j][1]), i, j});
    sort(edges1.begin(), edges1.end());
    auto t_end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double elapsed_time_ms1 = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end1 - t_start1).count();
    cout << elapsed_time_ms1 << endl;
```

Output:

```
241.917
1188.11
```

Does anyone know why there is a big difference in performance?

Comment: A `std::pair` knows exactly how much space it needs for its contents and is able to completely avoid objects with dynamic storage duration--in implementation terms, the heap. A `std::vector` needs this because it might have to store an unknown number of elements. In general, if you know in advance how many elements you'll need store, fixed-size containers like `std::pair` and `std::array` can have less overhead than `std::vector`.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization on?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I just tried with `reserve()`, but It does made much difference. Regarding the optimization option, I need to check. I am using CLion and I am new to C++. I look at the build options that CLion is using by default and update them here.

Comment: @NathanPierson does that mean pair stored the values in stack and vector tried to store in heap?

Comment: In a typical implementation, yes.

Comment: @KarthikNedunchezhiyan `std::vector` elements are not stored "on the stack" unless you do something very strange with the allocator. The difference between `std::vector<pair<int,int>>` and `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is that in the first case all the elements are essentially stored in contiguous storage. It's a lot like a `int[]` with 2 `int` per element (per pair). With the second approach, you basically have a vector of pointers to dynamically allocated arrays. Each insertion requires a whole new allocation.

Comment: You say "I just tried with `reserve()`" but what did you call `reserve()` on?  Just the vector `edges1`?  Did you also call it on each sub-vector of `edges1`?  Either way there are going to be a bunch of heap allocations there.    Just one heap allocation for `edges`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::pair` or `std::array` has a fixed size known at compile time and will include the objects directly in the class itself. A `std::vector` on the other hand has to deal with dynamic size and needs to allocate a chunk of memory on the heap to hold the objects.

For small objects the `std::pair` or `std::array` will be better because the overhead of allocating and freeing memory will eat into your performance. That's what you are seeing. The extra indirection involved with the pointer will also cost you when e.g. comparing the elements as well as having to check the size at run time.

On the other hand for large objects the `std::vector` should be better because it supports move semantics. Swapping 2 vectors will just swap the pointer to the data while `std::pair` or `std:array` will have to move/copy each element, which would be costly for large objects.

So what you see is not that pair is faster than vector but that pair is faster than vector in that use case.